# Vue - implementing this.$options.staticRenderFns

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am trying to implement a Vue Component with a custom render function.
As soon as my template has nested HTML elements, i get this error:

```
TypeError: this.$options.staticRenderFns is undefined
```

How do I implement *staticRenderFns*?

Code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" /> 
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <comp temp="temp1"></comp>
    </div>
    <script>
        var myTemplates = new Array();
        myTemplates['temp1'] = Vue.compile("<div><div>This template will come from an AJAX source</div></div>").render; 

        var Comp = {
          props: ["temp"], 
          data() {
            return {
                renderFunc: myTemplates[ this.$props.temp ],
            }
          },
          render(h) {
            return this.renderFunc()
          }
        };

        new Vue({
          el: "#app",
          data: { },
          components: { Comp }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you're just rendering raw html, why not just make it easy and use `v-html`?

Comment: I coded up the sample to demonstrate the problem I run into when I have nested elements. In my actual code the template contains placeholders.

Comment: I stumbled across this researching the `Vue.compile` method (https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-compile) -- it actually returns an object with the `render` and `staticRenderFns` which can be both be set on the object a Vue component is created from (your `Comp` object). Not certain whether this would really resolve your situation but I noticed the difference between current docs and your sample.